# What could cause a PHP socket request to be blocked?

Tags: php, sockets

I'm using [this](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query) PHP library to query a Minecraft server and get some information about it (players online, max players, etc.). It connects to the server via a socket and sends a request for the information, the server sends data back. When I was hosting the code on XAMPP on my personal computer, everything worked perfectly. Then I got a web host ([Bluehost](https://www.bluehost.com/)) and uploaded all the code and now the request times out every single time. I've used command prompt to ping the server address to ensure that it's up and responding, and it is.

Here's my code:

```
function pingPlayers($ip) {
    try {
        $Query = new MinecraftPing($ip);
        $response = $Query->Query();

        $players = $response['players']['online'];
        $maxPlayers = $response['players']['max'];
        $online = true;
    }
    catch(MinecraftPingException $e) {
        $players = "0";
        $maxPlayers = "0";
        $online = false;

        var_dump($e);
    } finally {
        $Query->Close();
    } 

    return array("players" => $players, "maxPlayers" => $maxPlayers, "status" => $online);
}
```

The [MinecraftPing class and all of it's functions can be found here.](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query/blob/master/src/MinecraftPing.php)

I am getting a MinecraftPingException returned, and it says "Failed to connect or create a socket: 110 (Connection timed out)". My first guess was that the host is blocking outgoing requests, but I contacted them and they said nothing is being blocked. I'm not getting any other errors besides the MinecraftPingException.

Comment: or the remote site is blocking on their end. maybe they've blacklisted your hosting provider.

Comment: @MarcB I didn't even think about that. I'll try to contact the remote site owners. Are there any other ways to check?

Comment: use alternate means, e.g. pop open a shell and try to telnet to various ports. even if you can't "talk" the protocol used on those ports, you'll at least be able to see a connection get established (or refused, or time out).